# Springboot, parent-child relation always has null on foreign key

Tags: spring

I'm developing a restaurant management program, using Java for the frontend, and Springboot for Backend. I'm having troubles saving an object.

I have two classes: Category and Dish.

Category contains a List, while Dish contains a Category for its foreign key. A dish can belong to only one category.

In my client, i create a Dish, and send it to the Backend using API REST, so it can save the dish in the database. But when i do this, the 'category' foreign key in 'dish' is ALWAYS null.

Maybe i'm using a wrong syntax, but i've been stuck on this for many days. There are too many variables i have to keep track of that could be giving me an error. This is my backend:

Category:

```
package com.springone3.demo.Entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table
public class Category {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "category_sequence",
            sequenceName = "category_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "category_sequence"
    )

    private Long idCategory;

    private String nameCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Dish> listDish;

Constructor...
```

Dish:

```
ackage com.springone3.demo.Entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;


@Entity
@Table
public class Dish {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "dish_sequence",
            sequenceName = "dish_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "dish_sequence"
    )

    private Long idDish;


    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String allergens;




    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "id_category",
            referencedColumnName = "idCategory"
    )

    private Category category;
    private String cost;

Constructor...
```

DishController:

```
package com.springone3.demo.Controller;

import com.springone3.demo.Entity.Piatto;
import com.springone3.demo.Service.PiattoService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.swing.text.html.Option;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/dish")
public class DishController {

    @Autowired
    private final DishService dishService;

    public DishController(DishService dishService) {
        this.dishService = dishService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/getDishes")
    public List<Dish> getDishes(){
        return dishService.getDishes();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/id/{idDish}")
    public Optional<Dish> getDishByID(@PathVariable Long idDish){
        return dishService.getDishByID(idDish);
    }

    @GetMapping("/nome/{nome}")
    public Optional<Dish> getDishByName(@PathVariable String nome){
        return dishService.getDishByName(nome);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/addDish", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void registerNewDish(Dish dish){
        dishService.addNewDish(dish);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = "/delete/{idDish}")
    public void deleteDish(@PathVariable("idDish") Long idDish){
        dishService.deleteDish(idDish);
    }

}
```

DishService:

```
package com.springone3.demo.Service;

import com.springone3.demo.Entity.Piatto;
import com.springone3.demo.Repository.PiattoRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class DishService {

    private final DishRepository dishRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DishService(DishRepository dishRepository) {
        this.dishRepository = dishRepository;
    }

    public List<Dish> getDishes() {
        return dishRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addNewDish(Dish dish) {
        Optional<Dish> dishByID = dishRepository
                .findDishByID(dish.getIdDish());
        if(dishByID.isPresent()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("dish already exists");
        }
        dishRepository.save(dish);
        System.out.println(dish);

    }

    public void deleteDish(Long idDish) {
        boolean exists = dishRepository.existsById(idDish);
        if(!exists){
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "dish with id " + idDish + "not exists.");
        }
        dishRepository.deleteById(idDish);
    }

    public Optional<Dish> getDishByName(String nome) {
        return dishRepository.findDishByName(nome);
    }

    public Optional<Dish> getDishByID(Long idDish) {
        Optional<Dish> optionalDish = dishRepository.findById(idDish);
        return Optional.ofNullable(optionalDish.orElse(null));
    }
}
```

DishRepository:

```
package com.springone3.demo.Repository;

import com.springone3.demo.Entity.Dish;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@Repository
public interface DishRepository extends JpaRepository<Dish, Long> {

    //SELECT * FROM dish WHERE id = ?
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Dish p WHERE p.idDish = ?1")
    Optional<Dish> findDishByID(Long id);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Dish p WHERE p.nome = ?1")
    Optional<Dish> findDishByName(String nome);

   // Optional<Dish> getDishByID(Long idDish);
    Optional<Dish> findById(Long id);
    List<Dish> findAll();
}
```

The REST Post method i use in my client:

```
@Override
    public void addDish(Dish dish) {
        try {
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dish/addDish")
                    .header("accept", "application/json")
                    .field("name", dish.getName())
                    .field("description", dish.getDescription())
                    .field("allergens", dish.getAllergens())
                    .field("cost", dish.getCost())
                    .field("category", dish.getCategory())
                    .asJson();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I read a lot of thread here about this problem with JPA but none was of any help for me. I posted just the backend code of my two entities, but remember i create a Dish in my client (and i do this my compiling a form, getting all the text from the textfields and using it to create a Dish. I don't think this is the problem, but if you think it could help i'll post that too).

Do you find any errors?

Comment: Hello, please share the code of backend where you are persisting the Dish (controller,  service and repository classes). And please also check and update the question text: private Categoria category; should be probably private Category category;

Comment: I added the remaining classes. If you find any mistakes in the naming (like the Categoria category you pointed out), i'm italian so i'm translating every name of the classes to give you a better understanding.

Comment: Do you have any info about the value of dish.getCategory() in your client code (the one that you pass for the category field)? Does it have any value? Or it’s null there already?

Comment: No, it's not null because i get it from the backend. I populate a combobox with Categories with a GET from the backend, and use that to create a Dish, then i send it to the backend. Before sending, i check the Dish values and it contains the category. When i send it, it arrives complete but without the category. I'll try right now what Mar-Z suggested!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a nested data object from frontend to backend. It is a complete Dish object with a Category assigned. This can't be send with simple fields and media type `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Use JSON instead. Try to change like this:

Old:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/addDish", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = 
    Unirest.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dish/addDish")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .field("name", dish.getName())
                .field("description", dish.getDescription())
                .field("allergens", dish.getAllergens())
                .field("cost", dish.getCost())
                .field("category", dish.getCategory())
                .asJson();
```

New:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/addDish")

HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = 
    Unirest.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dish/addDish")
                .body(dish)
                .asJson();
```

It is enough as JSON is default for Spring Boot.

Please also check if the Category in the request contains a valid id. The entity with this id should exist in the database prior to saving the Dish.

Comment: Again, thank you very much! I tried using your code, but it requires an object mapper. I'm trying to use Gson to serialize the body, but the dish arrives on the backend with all fields 'empty'. I'm trying to solve this problem. I want to make a different question now: i think your first approach (sending both the Dish AND the category ID to the backend) is actually the correct one, because on the frontend side, 'Dish' doesn't actually need a Category. It is something needed only for the database to use as foreign key. But i don't know how to send both a Dish AND a long to the backend endpoint.

Comment: Jackson ObjectMapper is part of standard Spring Boot configuration. Are you using starters in your pom.xml? This is the best way to get it work. spring-boot-starter-web contains Jackson library.